# How do I convert an UTF8 encoded emoji character to an image?

Tags: r, regex, utf-8, emoji

I have a long vector containing emojis, something like this:

```r
emojis <- c("","","","","")
```

and then I have their utf-8 encodings which I extracted with the help of `devtools::install_github( "ThinkRstat/utf8splain")` followed by `library(utf8splain)` like this, just for example: (not accurately represented)

```r
emojis_enc <- c()
for(i in 1:length(emojis)){
  emojis_enc <- c(emojis_enc, utf8splain::runes(emojis[i])$rune)
}
#emojis_enc <- c("U+12345","U+67891","U+91234","U+56789","U+123A6")
```

Then I have made a function this:

```r
emojiPlot <- function(photo_enc, emo_char){
  png(paste0(photo_enc, ".png"))
  plot(emo_char, rescale = T, ylim = c(-1,1), xlim = c(-1,1))
  dev.off()
}
```

And when I do this `emojiPlot("emojis_enc[1]", emojis[1])` I just get an empty plot with x and y axis. I am pretty novice with UTF and R.

The reason why I am doing is because I am using a plugin called "imagepreview" in gephi software. And the plugin requires the nodes as photos. So my goal is to have individual emojis in .png and give them their utf encodings as the name. So when I import my data, I can just point the CSV containing the utfs to the names of the photos and pull the right emoji. And then just graph it.

I am doing this for a research project. I am open to better ways to do it.

I am in Ubuntu OS. If you use Windows, then emojis will show as their correct utf format, and won't be rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution to get to the png files of the emojis is to download them from Twitter, which accepts runes in the urls linking to the png files:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(emojis = c("","","","","")) %>% 
  mutate(rune = map_chr(emojis, ~ utf8splain::runes(.)$rune)) %>%    # convert to runes
  mutate(rune = str_remove(rune, fixed("U+"))) %>%                   # remove leading U+
  mutate(emoji_url = paste0("https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v2/72x72/", # make url
                            tolower(rune), ".png"))

# download the files
map2(data$emoji_url, paste0(data$rune, ".png"), function(x, y) download.file(x, y, method = "curl"))
```

This will download the png files and place them in your working directory.

#### In base

The tidyverse code is optional, the same can be done in base:

```
emojis <- c("","","","","")
rune <- sapply(emojis, function(x) utf8splain::runes(x)$rune)
emojiurl <- paste0("https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v2/72x72/", tolower(rune), ".png")

for (i in seq_along(emojiurl)) {
  download.file(emojiurl[i], paste0(rune[i], ".png"), method = "curl")
}
```

Comment: Thanks JB, tidyverse and I don't go together well. I created blunder in past with mutate function in front of my mentor hehehe. But nonetheless, this is very appreciated. It is actually way faster than my current method.

Comment: Ah I see. I added an alternative in base. I had the tidyverse code lying around already but it's not necessary.

Comment: WOW, I should get into habit of using apply() functions. Thanks JB, you're the best!

Answer (score 1):

You are plotting characters with `plot` when you should be using `text`.
In the code below, a plot is created with `plot`, argument `type = "n"`, meaning, *don't plot* . Then the text (emoji) is added.

```
emojiPlot <- function(photo_enc, emo_char){
  png(paste0(photo_enc, ".png"), units = "cm",
      width = 10, height = 10, res = 600)
  plot(0, 0, xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), type = "n")
  text(0, 0, emo_char)
  dev.off()
}

emojiPlot("emojis_enc[1]", emojis[1])
```

The file `"emojis_enc[1].png"` is posted here:

[image]

Comment: Never thanked you. I really appreciate your help. Have a great day buddy!

Comment: @ToadPitt Glad it helped.